# How to deal with two libraries that need different versions of an assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# ASP.NET site that uses a 3rd party library with a dependency on JSON.NET.  It pulls in [Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0] as part of its reference.

Yesterday, I added a reference to a different 3rd party library with a dependency on the latest version of JSON.NET.  I'm now stuck in a situation where I can only get one of these libraries to work at any given time.

If I just drop the new reference in to the project, calls to it fail with:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0
```

... and if I update the JSON.NET dependency for the original library, the new code works fine but calls to the old library fail with:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.0.5.0
```

I can understand the first failure.  Fair enough, you need a newer version.  But the second one baffles me.  There are no breaking changes between version 4 and 9.  It should be able to use the newer .dll just fine.

Regardless, I'm at a point where I'm blocked.  I've neutered the new code and removed the references to the new library that causes the trouble.  But I don't have a plan for how to proceed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Third party components referencing different versions of the same assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699706/third-party-components-referencing-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need an [*assembly binding redirect*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, in your `web.config` file:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

That basically says "If you want to use any version of `Newtonsoft.Json` earlier than 9, just load v9 instead."

This only works *because* Json.NET hasn't made (many?) breaking changes between versions. With full SemVer, using major version numbers for breaking changes (and embracing that possibility), I suspect we'll see more difficult situations in the future...

Comment: Thanks for that.  In my case I was also running up against the issue where this section will be ignored if there's a namespace on the configuration section (mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12011221/150370), but this did fix the problem.